# Error en el datepicker con angular 6

Tags: css, angular

Tengo la siguiente advertencia en el compilador de angular:

> WARNING in ./src/css/datepicker.css
>   (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/css/datepicker.css)
>                     (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) autoprefixer: C:\Users\Estadias\Desktop\Proyecto\BI\src\css\datepicker.css:7:1439:
>   Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left`
>   instead of `right`.

Es un error de sintaxis?
Es en este fragmento de codigo:

```
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc); background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si traduces el error y lees [la documentación de gradientes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) te darás cuentas de que necesitas el prefijo `to` para dar la orientación del gradiente.

De esa manera lo que buscas se soluciona con

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0044cc); background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Comment: Ya remplace los top a to botton pero sigue sin funcionar solo desapareció una advertencia.

Comment: Que error te da ahora ?

Comment: Sigue siendo el mismo pero en otro archivo, el problema es que al compilar correctamente, no funciona el datepicker

Comment: Si te da el mismo error en otro archivo, solo tenés que editar ese otro archivo con el mismo código... O tal vez no te estoy entendiendo.